# Connect To SQL From CRM Dynamics 2011 Plugin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Hi All I posted a question earlier regarding, how to set an active contract to draft, but doing my research I found out it can either been done going straight into SQL doing the update or do it by copying the contract and then make an update. I had to go for option one. I'm trying to access my database and update the table, but get a SQL generic error from the plugin. My code to access the database from the plugin (I usually use Entity Framework to connect):

```
string strConn = "Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
connection.ConnectionString = strConn;
connection.Open();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "Update ContractBase set StateCode = 0,StatusCode = 1 "
  + "where ContractId = ACC70D43-DEBA-E111-8610-00155D041E80";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Is there anything else I need to consider when I connect to the database from the plugin? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know if its the cause of your error (you didn't post the error message), but you are missing single quotes on your filter: `where ContractId = 'ACC70D43-DEBA-E111-8610-00155D041E80'`

Comment: Yup thats what it was thanks alot...

Comment: No problem. Now that your issue is resolved, you can answer your question with the solution (and later, accept that answer)

Comment: You know this is massively unsupported right?

Comment: Hi James, yes I do know it is unsupported but it is required, I have to update a contract when it is active, and the two ways to do so is either go straight into SQL and set it to draft or copy the contract (becomes draft) and then update it. I had to pick oprion one and go into SQL, as the other way doesnt meet the clients business requirements, hence I have to go this way...

Comment: Why not use a plugin and catch the message *Create*?

Comment: Hmm, this isn't the option I would go with.

Answer (score 0):

Would the SetStateRequest message not be the appropriate way of setting the state and status?  or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes ideally this message, can be (and should be) used to set the state of an entity. However contracts can not be changed back to Draft once they are Active, therefore I had to do a workaround, which I know is not ideal (not supported)....

Comment: the only other thing I would consider is a "using" block for IDisposable objects, such as the SqlConnection

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is too late but you can create a SSIS package that stores CRM data in to SQL table. Create a simple plugin that on create or update fires of this SSIS package.

You will have to run this plugin with none isolation mode as the sandbox isolation will not allow file access (package).